# Difference between ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER) and ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA)?

Tags: c, system-calls, strace, ptrace

After posting a lot of questions on `ptrace` (the most recent 5 questions are mine :( ) I finally got the desired output when I replaced

```
reg_val[1] = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, child, 4 * EBX, NULL);
```

with

```
reg_val[1] = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, child, 4 * EBX, NULL);
```

The difference mentioned in man page is like this

- `PTRACE_PEEKTEXT` reads a word at the location addr in the child's memory
- `PTRACE_PEEKUSER` reads a word at offset addr in the child's USER area

I am unable to understand this difference alone from the man page. Can any one educate me more on this??

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`PTRACE_PEEKDATA` is for reading the data/code section of the child (process in general -- the so called tracee). As you know, debuggers use `ptrace` a lot. They can use this call to examine values of variables. For example, in `GDB/DBX`, if you say

```
print count
```

the debuggers will internally invoke `ptrace` with `PTRACE_PEEKDATA` and find its value.

`PTRACE_PEEKUSER` is used to read the contents of the child's USER area which holds contents of registers and other info. [sys/user.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/fc6eabbbf8ef99efed778dd5afabc83c21dba585/arch/x86/include/asm/user_64.h#L69) lists what is that other info.

For example USER area contains,

```
struct user_regs_struct
{
  long int ebx;
  long int ecx;
  long int edx;
  long int esi;
  long int edi;
  long int ebp;
  long int eax;
  long int xds;
  long int xes;
  long int xfs;
  long int xgs;
  long int orig_eax;
  long int eip;
  long int xcs;
  long int eflags;
  long int esp;
  long int xss;
};
```

**In short**:

- `PTRACE_PEEKDATA` is for program data (e.g. variables) and code;
- `PTRACE_PEEKUSER` is for things like register values and other debug info;

*Notice the equivalence between `PTRACE_PEEKDATA` and `PTRACE_PEEKTEXT`. From [`man ptrace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)*:

> Linux does not have separate text and data address spaces, so these two requests are currently equivalent.

Comment: `PTRACE_PEEKDATA is for things like register values and other debug info.`
Aren't ebx, ecx register values?? :O I thought so. By registers what all did you mean? `EIP` (instruction pointer)??

Comment: sorry for the typo. I corrected it. **PTRACE_PEEKUSER** is for registers and **NOT** **PTRACE_PEEKDATA**

Comment: Your last sentence is confusing me (is it a typo??). You said peekdata is for program data. fine with tat. Now again you say peekdata is for registers !! Did you mean peekuser??

Comment: Hi there; so sorry to resurrect an ancient post, but was wondering: where is the child's USER area actually stored in virtual memory? I know that this will likely be implementation specific, but – say – on Ubuntu 64 bit, where in virtual memory is PTRACE_PEEKUSER actually looking? Thanks so much in advance

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I think the 'user area' is an area for the process to store meta-data in kernel space, and this data is only mapped/copied into userspace for this call to ptrace.